# How to check if data is being sent in mobileVLCkit

Tags: xcode

I'm creating a video streaming player, using mobileVLCkit. 
and want to know if the video data of requested URL is being sent.
What code should I write?

I'm using Xcode 10, swift 4, mobileVLCkit for VLCMediaPlayer.

```
///// below is my code
myPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer.shared
myPlayer.media = VLCMedia(url : URL(string : myURL)!)
myPlayer.drawable = self.myPlayer_view
myPlayer.play()

///// below is what i tried 
myPlayer.media.isplaying() // not worked
func mediaPlayerStateChanged(_ aNotification: Notification!) {} // not worked
```

When I tried
    myPlayer.media.isplaying(),
I expected I could check there is data. 
But It is simply player is playing or not.
So If there is video data but it is stopped, The result is
    myPlayer.media.isplaying() = false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the state with `VLCMediaPlayerDelegate`.

Don't forget to set your player as the delegate for example:

`myPlayer.delegate = self`

Then listen for the changes like so:

```
 extension PlaybackViewController: VLCMediaPlayerDelegate {
    func mediaPlayerStateChanged(_ aNotification: Notification!) {
        if mediaPlayer.state == .playing {
            // Currently playing...
        }
        // Handle other states...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. but i couldn't use this, because there is no instance or method like 'mediaPlayer.state' in my code. i tried 'player.media.state' instead, but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Did you correctly put your class as a delegate of `VLCMediaPlayerDelegate`?

Comment: Yes. I put `VLCMediaPlayerDelegate`.
But It looks like `mediaPlayer` is not in `VLCMediaPlayerDelegate`. I referenced here : http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/MobileVLCKit/2.2.1/Protocols/VLCMediaPlayerDelegate.html

Comment: Have a look at the sample Swift project, maybe it will help you! https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit/tree/master/Examples/iOS/SwiftSimplePlayback